# Rails Routing from a plural to singular resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I had built a feature in my app in which I had created some content settings that could be changed within my database. However I ran into an issue that required me to use a polymorphic route.  This ended up causing me lots of issues because my routes had two ID's associated with them. I realized that the reason why this was the case was that my resource in my routes file was plural. So I made it singular, and now i'm having issues getting the simple routes to work out.

My routes file is like so

```
concern :content_settings do
  resources :content_setting, only: [:index, :edit, :delete, :update]
end
```

When I run a rake routes I'm getting so

```
admin_customer_content_setting_index GET     /admin/customers/:customer_id/content_setting(.:format)              admin/content_setting#index
edit_admin_customer_content_setting  GET     /admin/customers/:customer_id/content_setting/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/content_setting#edit
admin_customer_content_setting       PATCH   /admin/customers/:customer_id/content_setting/:id(.:format)          admin/content_setting#update   
                                     PUT     /admin/customers/:customer_id/content_setting/:id(.:format)          admin/content_setting#update
```

Now basically I am at a point where I need to implement a route to the editing options of my new awesome feature.  I keep trying something along the lines of..

```
=link_to edit_admin_customer_content_setting_path(@owner)
```

I continue getting a 'no route options' error.  Would anybody know if there is something that I am missing? I'm happy to show more of my code if needed.

Much thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this

```
= link_to edit_admin_customer_content_setting_path(customer_id: @owner.id, id: @content.id)
```

When you take a look at the output of the `rake routes`, you can see that in the third column you are being told what parameters it expects:

```
edit_admin_customer_content_setting  GET     /admin/customers/:customer_id/content_setting/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/content_setting#edit
```

In your case: `customer_id` and `id`

---

UPDATE

If you would like to avoid passing two ids to your helpers, you can use shallow routes. Please take a look at the [documentation here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) (scroll little bit down to **Shallow Nesting**)

Comment: Oh my, you are a genius! Thank you so much @bosskovic  The routes are properly working now!